# JavaScript implementation of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-of-life

It took some time to make Conway's Game of Life in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery. I'd like suggestions, criticisms, and discussions on how it can be done better.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/64Leueeu/)

```js
/*
 * Conway's - Game of Life.
 * Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
 * Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
 * Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by over-population.
 * Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.
 */

'use strict';

/*
 * Representation of each cell on the canvas.
 * "row" and "col" stores the location of the cell.
 * The "alive" property stores whether the cell is alive or dead.
 */
function Cell(row, col) {

  var _this = this,
    $this = null,
    alive = false;

  this.activate = function () {
    alive = true;
    $this.addClass('alive');
  };

  this.deActivate = function () {
    alive = false;
    $this.removeClass('alive');
  };

  this.isAlive = function () {
    return alive;
  };

  this.getRow = function () {
    return row;
  };

  this.getCol = function () {
    return col;
  };

  this.getJqueryElement = function () {
    return $this;
  };

  // If $this is not yet defined, create a new HTML element.
  if (null === $this) {
    $this = $('<div>').addClass('conway-cell').data('cell', _this);
  }

  return this;
}

/**
 * The main logic of the game goes here.
 */
function ConwayGame(selector, numRows, numCols) {

  var $parent = $(selector),
    _this = this,
    rows = numRows,
    cols = numCols,
    cells = [],
    lifeMap = [],
    intervalTime = 500,
    intervalId;

  this.getSpeed = function () {
    return intervalTime;
  };

  // Initialize the list of cells required. Add the same to the HTML parent element.
  var initialize = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

      cells[i] = [];
      var $row = $('<div>').addClass('conway-row');

      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        var cell = cells[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
        var $cell = cell.getJqueryElement();

        // Add click handler for the Cell.
        $cell.on('click', function (event) {
          var cellObj = $(this).data('cell');
          if (cellObj.isAlive()) {
            cellObj.deActivate()
          } else {
            cellObj.activate();
          }

          _this.reMap();
        });

        $row.append($cell);
      }

      // Add the HTML Row to the Parent element.
      $parent.append($row);
    }
  };

  // Re-draw the Elements based on their status, if they are alive or not.
  this.reDraw = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        var cell = cells[i][j];
        cell.isAlive() ? cell.activate() : cell.deActivate();
      }
    }

  };

  // Get the count of immediate neighbors for the cell.
  this.getNeighborsCount = function (cell) {

    var neighbors = 0,
      row = cell.getRow(),
      col = cell.getCol();

    // Top Left to Top Right
    if (cells[row - 1]) {
      if (cells[row - 1][col - 1] && cells[row - 1][col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
      if (cells[row - 1][col] && cells[row - 1][col].isAlive()) neighbors++;
      if (cells[row - 1][col + 1] && cells[row - 1][col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    }

    // Middle Left to Middle Right. Ignore the current cell.
    if (cells[row][col - 1] && cells[row][col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    if (cells[row][col + 1] && cells[row][col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;

    // Bottom Left to Bottom Right.
    if (cells[row + 1]) {
      if (cells[row + 1][col - 1] && cells[row + 1][col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
      if (cells[row + 1][col] && cells[row + 1][col].isAlive()) neighbors++;
      if (cells[row + 1][col + 1] && cells[row + 1][col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    }

    return neighbors;
  };

  this.reMap = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      lifeMap[i] = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        var cell = cells[i][j];
        lifeMap[i][j] = _this.getNeighborsCount(cell);
      }
    }
  };

  this.getNextLife = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

        var cell = cells[i][j];
        var lifeValue = lifeMap[i][j];

        if (cell.isAlive()) {
          if (lifeValue < 2 || lifeValue > 3) {
            cell.deActivate();
          }
        } else {
          if (lifeValue === 3) {
            cell.activate();
          }
        }

      }
    }

    _this.reMap();
  };

  this.next = function () {
    _this.getNextLife();
    _this.reDraw();
  };

  this.play = function () {
    intervalId = setInterval(_this.next, intervalTime);
  };

  this.pause = function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  this.increaseSpeed = function () {
    if (intervalTime > 100) {
      intervalTime -= 100;
    }
    _this.pause();
    _this.play();
  };

  this.decreaseSpeed = function () {
    if (intervalTime < 2000) {
      intervalTime += 100;
    }
    _this.pause();
    _this.play();
  };

  if (cells.length === 0) {
    initialize();
  }

  return this;
}


// Run as soon as the Document is Ready.
$(function () {

  var game = new ConwayGame('.conway-game', 20, 20);

  $('#nextButton').on('click', function () {
    game.next();
  });

  $('#playButton').on('click', function () {
    game.play();
  });

  $('#pauseButton').on('click', function () {
    game.pause();
  });

  $('#speedUpButton').on('click', function () {
    game.increaseSpeed();
  });

  $('#slowDownButton').on('click', function () {
    game.decreaseSpeed();
  });

});
```

```css
.conway-game {
  display: table;
}

.conway-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.conway-cell {
  display: table-column;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCE8AF;
}

.alive {
  background-color: #7FC539;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.controls button {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conway-game"></div>
<div class="controls">
  <button id="playButton">Play</button>
  <button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
  <button id="nextButton">Step</button>

  <button id="speedUpButton">Speed Up</button>
  <button id="slowDownButton">Slow Down</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use an interval. Use requestanimationframe and recur in the callback

Comment: You can also consider to use ES6 for OOP/Classes and modularity, and transpile it using BabelJS. That's also good for reusability in future, IMHO

Comment: @Zorgatone, yeah am looking into the `requestanimationframe` method. I did take a look at ES6, I don't think I'll be changing my code for that. Thanks for the comments. :)

Comment: No problem, however having a good grasp at ES6 can be really helpful

Comment: You will get better performance out of a canvas/SVG than table cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cloned your code and created a [website](http://malachi26.github.io/gameoflife-vanilla.html) using the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/malachi26/malachi26.github.io) that I created with it so you can see some of the other changes that I make to the code as well. please feel free to fork it.

---

In the `initialize` function of your `ConwayGame` class you used the length if then statement

> ```
> if (cellObj.isAlive()) {
>   cellObj.deActivate()
> } else {
>   cellObj.activate();
> }
> ```

But then in the `this.reDraw` function you use a ternary statement for the same call, so I changed that right away.  I know that these are reversed, but the ternary will operate in a similar fashion.  It looks like this

```
cellObj.isAlive() ? cellObj.deActivate() : cellObj.activate();
```

---

I also removed some of the comments because they were redundant when I looked at the line(s) of code that they were referring to.

---

I also lightly touched the `getNeightborscount` function and changed it slightly, I pulled out `rowAbove` and `rowBelow` so that I could dry it up a little bit, but I was only able to pull these out so far, this is what it looks like currently

```
this.getNeighborsCount = function (cell) {

    var neighbors = 0,
    row = cell.getRow(),
    col = cell.getCol();

    var rowAbove = cells[row - 1];
    var rowBelow = cells[row + 1];

    //if (cells[row - 1]) {
    if (rowAbove) {
        if (rowAbove[col - 1] && rowAbove[col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
        if (rowAbove[col] && rowAbove[col].isAlive()) neighbors++;
        if (rowAbove[col + 1] && rowAbove[col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    }

    if (cells[row][col - 1] && cells[row][col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    if (cells[row][col + 1] && cells[row][col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;

    //if (cells[row + 1]) {
    if (rowBelow) {
        if (rowBelow[col - 1] && rowBelow[col - 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
        if (rowBelow[col] && rowBelow[col].isAlive()) neighbors++;
        if (rowBelow[col + 1] && rowBelow[col + 1].isAlive()) neighbors++;
    }

    return neighbors;
};
```

---

Let's move on to the `this.getNextLife` function.

> ```
> if (cell.isAlive()) {
>   if (lifeValue < 2 || lifeValue > 3) {
>       cell.deActivate();
>       cellsDestroyed++;
>   }
> } else {
>   if (lifeValue === 3) {
>       cell.activate();
>       cellsCreated++;
>   }
> }
> ```

this looks a little clunky to me, at the very least that else statement should be an else if statement like this

```
if (cell.isAlive()) {
    if (lifeValue < 2 || lifeValue > 3) {
        cell.deActivate();
        cellsDestroyed++;
    }
} else if (lifeValue === 3) {
    cell.activate();
    cellsCreated++;
}
```

---

I liked the way that you created classes and objects to handle the different functions of the Game itself so you could just call them on a click event.

---

**Edit:**
I found a bug in your code, you were counting surviving cells as newly created cells inside the `getNextLife` function.  Here is how I fixed that.

```
if (cell.isAlive()) {
    if (lifeValue < 2 || lifeValue > 3) {
        cell.deActivate();
        cellsDestroyed++;
    } else if (lifeValue === 3) {
        cell.activate();
    }
} else if (lifeValue === 3){
        cell.activate();
        cellsCreated++;
    }
}
```

And really I don't think that you need to actually activate that cell or do anything to it if it is active and has  `lifeValue === 3`

so we could just write it like this instead

```
if (cell.isAlive() && (lifeValue < 2 || lifeValue > 3) {
    cell.deActivate();
    cellsDestroyed++;
} else if (lifeValue === 3){
    cell.activate();
    cellsCreated++;
}
```

All these updates are in the code @GitHub as well.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful review. Cool, the GITHub repo looks nice with the user entering the number of cells. I agree with all the code changes that you have mentioned and updated the same in my Fiddle. It's been a while since I've looked at this code, I guess few things have been left unfinished and needs to be taken care of. Yup, this was my first *real* JavaScript application with OOP in mind..

Comment: please feel free to fork that repo, and do some pull requests.  I am thinking about how i would write the checking algorithm recursively, then I might post the code here for a review.